# PSQL Head to Head Records by Date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am looking for a way to update stats for contacts compared to another contact by day. I would like the expected data table to include the historical results for each contact they are paired with.

Completed Data

| id | date | contact1 | contact2 | contact1_orders | contact2_orders |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-04-01 | bob | joe | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-04-02 | bob | joe | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2021-04-03 | jim | tim | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2021-04-04 | tim | jim | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 2021-04-05 | joe | bob | 1 | 2 |
| 6 | 2021-04-06 | joe | bob | 1 | 2 |

Expected data for upcoming dates – updated with head to head results for each contact vs a different contact, respectively.

| id | date | contact1 | contact2 | contact1_h2h | contact2_h2h |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-04-01 | bob | joe | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2021-04-02 | bob | joe | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 2021-04-03 | jim | tim | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 2021-04-04 | tim | jim | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 2021-04-05 | joe | bob | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | 2021-04-06 | joe | bob | 3 | 1 |

Example, Bob and Joe were paired up 4 times prior to row 7. Bob ordered more than Joe 3 times and Joe ordered more than Bob 1 time.

**contact1_orders** is the number of orders placed by contact1 on a given date(or row id).

**contact2_orders** is the number of orders placed by contact2 on a given date(or row id).

**contact1_h2h** is the number of previous records where contact1 was paired with contact2 where contact1 placed more orders than contact2.

**contact2_h2h** is the number of previous records where contact2 was paired with contact where contact2 placed more orders than contact1.

I am looking for a query to update contact1_h2h and contact2_h2h in the expected data table with the number of days a contact ordered more than the contact they are associated with.

Comment: There are two columns and you have only explained one.  Further, I don't follow the explanation.  It doesn't seem to apply to jim/tim.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added explanations for columns. Please let me know if this is helpful or if you would like further explanation.

Comment: . . I still don't think your numbers are right.  Joe loses to Bob, but you are incrementing the wrong column.  In addition, some rows include the row in the logic, some don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you want.  You want the number of times that each person "wins" based on the comparison between the values.

The following query puts the results in a canonical format -- alphabetically -- to determine the counts:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) filter (where is_c1_win) over (partition by c1, c2 order by date)  as c1_h2h,
       count(*) filter (where is_c2_win) over (partition by c1, c2 order by date) as c2_h2h
from (select t.*, least(contact1, contact2) as c1,
             greatest(contact1, contact2) as c2,
             (contact1_orders > contact2_orders and contact1 < contact2 or
              contact2_orders > contact1_orders and contact2 < contact1
             ) as is_c1_win,
             (contact1_orders > contact2_orders and contact1 > contact2 or
              contact2_orders > contact1_orders and contact2 > contact1
             ) as is_c2_win
      from t
     ) t;
```

Then you can reassign these back to the original ordering of the contacts:

```
with h2h as (
      select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where is_c1_win) over (partition by c1, c2 order by date)  as c1_h2h,
             count(*) filter (where is_c2_win) over (partition by c1, c2 order by date) as c2_h2h
      from (select t.*, least(contact1, contact2) as c1,
                   greatest(contact1, contact2) as c2,
                   (contact1_orders > contact2_orders and contact1 < contact2 or
                    contact2_orders > contact1_orders and contact2 < contact1
                   ) as is_c1_win,
                   (contact1_orders > contact2_orders and contact1 > contact2 or
                    contact2_orders > contact1_orders and contact2 > contact1
                   ) as is_c2_win
            from t
           ) t
      )
select h2h.*,
       (case when contact1 < contact2 then c1_h2h else c2_h2h end) as contact1_h2h,
       (case when contact1 < contact2 then c2_h2h else c1_h2h end) as contact2_h2h
from h2h
order by id;
```

The results are different from your results, but these seem correct.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=898c237562df27dd260affc8513fe14a) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Gordon! I have been working on this endlessly for over a week. I was really close but couldn't figure out the last row for some reason. I truly appreciate your support and will find a way to pay it forward.